# How to have multiple conditionals in an if statement in Ada

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, ada

How would I go about having multiple conditionals in an if statement?

Eg. The user is asked a set of questions by the program:

1.) Enter an altitude between 0 and 1000

(user types in data)

2.) Enter Velocity between 0 and 500

(user types in data)

3.) Enter Temperature between 0 and 200

(user types in data)

the program then prints back

1. altitude = user value
2. velocity = user value
3. temperature = user value //ignore those list numbers

I have set in my (.ads) file that each of these ranges has a criticle value.

I want to create an if statement that has multiple conditionals.
in pseudo : If velocity = critical velocity & temperature = critical    temperature & altitude = critical altitude
then print ("some message")
else do nothing

Answer (score 5):

The [syntax of an if-statement](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-5-3.html) is

```
if_statement ::= 
    if condition then
      sequence_of_statements
   {elsif condition then
      sequence_of_statements}
   [else
      sequence_of_statements]
    end if;
```

and the [syntax of “condition”](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-5-7.html#p4) is

```
condition ::= boolean_expression
```

(that is, an expression which happens to be boolean); the [syntax of “expression”](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-4.html#S0117) is

```
expression ::= 
     relation {and relation}  | relation {and then relation}
   | relation {or relation}  | relation {or else relation}
   | relation {xor relation}
```

so your code would look like

```
if velocity = critical_velocity 
   and temperature = critical_temperature 
   and altitude = critical_altitude 
then 
   print ("some message”); 
else
   null;
end if;
```

You can leave out the `else` clause, and you can say `and then` instead of plain `and` if for some reason you shouldn’t check the rest of the condition if the first part is already `False`. This is called short-circuit evaluation, and it’s *not* the default in Ada (it is in C).

```
if X /= 0 and Y / X > 2 then
```

evaluates `Y / X` even if X is 0.

Comment: Thank you Simon! A very iterative breakdown, very helpful :)

Comment: here is a link to another question that I couldnt ask in the comments because it was too long for a comment. If you could please shed some light it would be much appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957726/shortened-method-to-reduce-statements-in-an-ada-procedure

Answer (score 4):

In Ada you will use the **and**, **or** and **not** boolean operator:

```
if Velocity = Critical_Velocity
  and Temperature = Critical_Temperature
  and Altitude = Critical_Altitude
then
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Crash");
else
  ...
end if;
```

When evaluation order matters, you will use the **and then** or the **or else** syntax (otherwise the compiler can change order for optimization).
Expressions will be evaluated in the 'and then'/'or else' order.

```
if Velocity = Critical_Velocity
  and then Temperature = Critical_Temperature
  and then Altitude = Critical_Altitude
then
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Crash");
else
  ...
end if;
```

With an **or else**, you may write as follows:

```
if Velocity = Critical_Velocity
  or else Temperature = Critical_Temperature
  or else Altitude = Critical_Altitude
then
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Crash");
else
  ...
end if;
```

Beware that you cannot mix **and** and **or** together (because this leads to many confusion for developers).
You have to use parenthesis arround them if you do it.

```
if (Velocity = Critical_Velocity and Temperature = Critical_Temperature)
  or else Altitude = Critical_Altitude
then
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Crash");
else
  ...
end if;
```

Comment: There is also xor.